# Pass the value to Jquery function from link button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to pass the parameter to jquery function from the link button.I need to pass **val1 ,val 2 values** to getdata function.

```
var val="Need to pass this first string to another jquery Function";
var val2="Need to pass this second string to another jquery Function";

<a id='myLink' href='#' onclick='getData()' >Link Text</a>


function getdata()
{
  //I need to here
}
```

Comment: but val1 and val2 can be directly use in getData() function, why do want to send them from link?

Comment: You have not provided enough information to properly answer this question. Why do you need to pass strings stored in variables to the functions? How do you know (and we know) which values are required?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to pass it through links, put those values in some hidden field like bellow:

```
<input type="hidden" id="val" value="Need to pass this first string to another jquery Function">
```

now get it in jquery function as bellow;

```
var value1 = $('#val').val();
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try something like this?

```
$('#myLink').click(function () {
    getdata(val, val2);
});
```

This will be placed in js file. Not html file. But this works fine.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Pass Parameter in event handler like this

```
var val="Need to pass this first string to another jquery Function";
var val2="Need to pass this second string to another jquery Function";

$('#myLink').on("click" , {arg1:val , arg2:val2}, getData);

function getData(event){

    event.preventDefault();

    alert(event.data.arg1); // Need to pass this first string to another jquery Function
    alert(event.data.arg2); // Need to pass this second string to another jquery Function
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works quite well:

HTML

```
<a id='myLink' href='#' onclick="getData(this)">Link Text</a>
```

Javascript

```
function getData(element){
  alert(element.innerHTML);
}
```

[Example Codepen](http://codepen.io/nickgofly/pen/xEFzC)

Comment: Read the question wrong. The other answers provide sufficient solutions. I'll leave this answer here just in case anybody looks for such a thing (getting the value of the clicked link).

Answer (score 0):

If the values are defined as you have, it does not make sense to pass them to the function; they are available to the function already.

We use arguments to pass data that's specific to the element that was interacted with via the event. One advantage of using jQuery is that inside the function 'this' refers to the element that was, clicked for example. This you can access all it's properties and attributes.

```
$('#myLink').on('click', getdata);

function getdata() {
    var lnText = $(this).text(); // for example
    //
}
```

Inline JS is not recommended:

```
<a id='myLink' href='#'>Link Text</a>
```